# O que são variáveis livre e ligada em Prolog?

Tags: característica-linguagem, prolog

O que se define como variável livre ou ligada. Dei uma leve pesquisada, mas não consegui entender muito bem o conceito matemático e diferenciá-las.

Se possível, explicar com exemplos definidos em Prolog mostrando quando uma variável é dita livre e quando ligada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma variável livre é uma variável que ainda não possui um valor. Uma ligada é uma que possui (e na ausência de *backtracking* após uma variável receber um valor ela está ligada a ele para sempre, não sendo possível lhe atribuir um outro valor).

Exemplo:

```
?- member(X, Y).
Y = [X|_G3168] .
```

Ao chamar `member/2`, tanto `X` quanto `Y` eram variáveis livres. Após a chamada, `Y` passou a estar ligada a uma lista (iniciada com `X` e terminada com qualquer coisa). `X` continua livre, de modo que você pode atribuir-lhe o valor que você quiser:

```
?- member(X, Y), X = 42.
X = 42,
Y = [42|_G3116] .
```

Enquanto `Y` não está mais livre, se você tentar unificá-la com algo diferente do que ela é (uma lista com no mínimo um elemento) a execução vai falhar (provocando um *backtrack*):

```
?- member(X, Y), !, Y = 42.
false.
```

(o corte é pra evitar um loop infinito, pois `member/2` continuaria gerando novos `Y`s, falhando e voltando)

Note que como o *conteúdo* de `Y` contém variáveis livres, você pode unificá-la com outra lista compatível com ela. Você não estaria mudando o seu valor - a lista continuaria a mesma. Só seus elementos (cabeça e cauda) que antes eram livres e vão deixar de ser:

```
?- member(X, Y), Y = [1,2,3,4,5].
X = 1,
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .
```

(nesse ponto você poderia pedir "mais soluções" para obter os demais valores de `X`, mas no final também cairia num loop infinito).

### Verificando se uma variável é ou não livre

Se você quiser saber se uma variável possui ou não um valor, não adianta compará-la com alguma outra coisa - já que compará-la vai acabar por unificá-la com aquela coisa e portanto torná-la ligada. Em vez disso, use os predicados `var/1` e `nonvar/1` que têm sucesso se a variável é livre/ligada respectivamente:

```
?- member(X, Y), var(X), nonvar(Y).
Y = [X|_G4611629] .

?- member(X, Y), !, var(Y).
false.

?- member(X, Y), !, nonvar(X).
false.
```